# ¿Cómo hago para salir de un thread?

Tags: python, hilos, selenium-webdriver, telegram-bot

Hace unas semanas comence un proyecto, soy bastante nuevo en el tema asi que cualquier corrección y aprendizaje me vendría bien.
El programa se trata de pasarle informacion a los usuarios que la pidan. Ellos piden mediante telegram y el programa busca en internet por selenium y les pasa lo pedido.
El tema es que pueden haber varios usuarios pidiendo informacion al mismo tiempo, por lo que necesito que haga varias tareas a la vez y no esperar a que termine la de un usuario anterior.
Mi problema es que no va al comando con el return, vuelve a pedirme que ingrese si o no y me vuelve a hacer el mismo procedimiento para pasarme la informacion. Nunca sale del def confirmaelticket.

Aca va el programa:

```
def confirmaelticket(update, context):
    t = TicketThread(update, context, resultado)
    t.start()
    
class TicketThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, update, context, callback_context):
        super(TicketThread, self).__init__()
        self.update = update
        self.context = context
        self.callback_context = callback_context

    def run(self):
        try:
            respuesta = self.update.message.text.lower()
            if respuesta == "si":
                try:
                    mensaje_a_supervisores = f'El usuario {self.context.user_data["Usuario"]} inició con el ticket: {self.context.user_data["Ticket"]}.'
                    enviar_mensaje_a_supervisores(self.context, mensaje_a_supervisores)
                    self.context.user_data["TicketEnCurso"] = True
                    self.update.message.reply_text(f"Perfecto. Estoy buscando la información de su ticket. Espere unos segundos.")
                    # Ingresa a la página
                    try:
                        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=OpcionesChrome)
                        driver.maximize_window()
                        # Realiza las tareas a la perfección en simultaneo
                        recibecomandos = True
                        self.context.user_data['RecibeComandos'] = recibecomandos
                        result = "ESPERAORDENES"
                        self.context.user_data['result'] = result
                        return self.callback_context(result, self.update, self.context) 
def resultado (result, update, context):
    print(f"Resultado: {context.user_data['result']}")
    if result == "ESPERAORDENES":
        return ESPERAORDENES
    if result == "ESPERAERROR":
        return ESPERAERROR
```